# Difficult Query: Can Only Modify The WHERE Clause

Tags: sql-server

Table `tblDistResell` (the first row is the column headers):

```
DISTRIBUTOR RESELLER    STATE
ABC         BestBuy     CA
ABC         RadioShack  NJ
XYZ         BestBuy     CA
XYZ         RadioShack  MO
```

Query:

```
SELECT Distributor
WHERE
(
(Reseller = 'BestBuy' AND [State]='CA') OR (Reseller = 'RadioShack' AND [State]='NJ')
);
```

Resultset:

```
DISTRIBUTOR  RESELLER    STATE
ABC          BestBuy     CA
ABC          RadioShack  NJ
XYZ          BestBuy     CA
```

When **EVERY** row for a distributor is returned, we want the count (or the resultset; whatever's easier).

But if only **ONE** (or more) distributor record(s) aren't returned, we want to ignore all of that distributor's results.

In other words, given the example above, we want to see either,

```
DISTRIBUTOR  RESELLER    STATE
ABC          BestBuy     CA
ABC          RadioShack  NJ
```

or

```
count == 2
```

(No XYZ records, since the RadioShack, MO record is missing from the resultset.)

Here's one more example for clarity...

Let's use the same table, `tbltblDistResell`, but a modified query:

```
SELECT Distributor                                              
WHERE                                               
(                                               
(Reseller = 'BestBuy' AND [State]='MO') OR (Reseller = 'RadioShack' AND [State]='NJ')
);
```

In this case, the following is returned:

```
DISTRIBUTOR  RESELLER    STATE
ABC          RadioShack  NJ
```

But since there is some ABC data that wasn't returned, we want to see either:

```
(0 row(s) affected)
```

or

```
count == 0
```

The challenge is that the tool we're using **only allows us to modify the WHERE clause!**

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Greg

Comment: Throw the tool away ;)

Comment: A simple `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... ;` query **cannot** do what you require. It'll have to be something more complicated. Either a cte or a derived table with window functions or a join with group by, etc. But certainly nothing simple.

Answer (score 2):

Count the number of rows for every distribution and compare that to the number of rows returned for a distribution where you apply your filter.

```
declare @T table
(
  Distributor char(3),
  Reseller varchar(10),
  State char(2)
);

insert into @T values
('ABC', 'BestBuy',    'CA'),
('ABC', 'RadioShack', 'NJ'),
('XYZ', 'BestBuy',    'CA'),
('XYZ', 'RadioShack', 'MO');

select T1.Distributor
from @T as T1
where (
      select count(*)
      from @T as T2
      where T1.Distributor =T2.Distributor
      ) = 
      (
      select count(*)
      from @T as T3
      where T1.Distributor =T3.Distributor and  
            (
            T3.Reseller = 'BestBuy' and T3.State='CA' or 
            T3.Reseller = 'RadioShack' and T3.State='NJ'
            )
      );

select T1.Distributor
from @T as T1
where (
      select count(*)
      from @T as T2
      where T1.Distributor =T2.Distributor
      ) = 
      (
      select count(*)
      from @T as T3
      where T1.Distributor =T3.Distributor and  
            (
            T3.Reseller = 'BestBuy' and T3.State='MO' or 
            T3.Reseller = 'RadioShack' and T3.State='NJ'
            )
      );
```

Comment: Thank you very much for putting the time & effort into this... Truly appreciated and helpful!